# Input function inside modal box

Tags: r, shiny

There is a radioButtons inside the modalbox. Is there a way to find what the user has selected inside the modal box

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("submit","Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    showModal(modalDialog(size = "l",title = "Insert",
                          radioButtons("where", "Where", choices = colnames(iris),inline = TRUE),
                          fluidPage(
                            colnames(iris)
                          ),
                          footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"),actionButton("confirm", "Confirm"))))
    
   
})
  
  ## I need to know what is been selected?
  print(input$where)
  
  
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

FOr example, I am printing `print(input$where)` but not able to see what is been selected?

Answer (score 0):

You've had two issues with your code:

- you can't print a vector of text (as returned by `colnames`)
- you cannot use a `reactive` as `input$where` outside of a reactive context

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("submit","Submit"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selection")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    showModal(modalDialog(size = "l",title = "Insert",
                          radioButtons("where", "Where", choices = colnames(iris),inline = TRUE),
                          fluidPage(
                            paste0(colnames(iris), collapse = " ")
                          ),
                          footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"),actionButton("confirm", "Confirm"))))
    
    
  })
  
  # I need to know what is been selected?
  output$selection <- renderPrint({
    print(input$where)
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Edit

To print it to the console you can use an observer:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("submit","Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    showModal(modalDialog(size = "l",title = "Insert",
                          radioButtons("where", "Where", choices = colnames(iris),inline = TRUE),
                          fluidPage(
                            paste0(colnames(iris), collapse = " ")
                          ),
                          footer = tagList(modalButton("Cancel"),actionButton("confirm", "Confirm"))))
    
    
  })
  
  # I need to know what is been selected?
 observeEvent(input$where, {
   print(input$where)
 })
  
  
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I see. But I only need to see the output in the R console and not in application. So basically I may not need input$selection? Right

Comment: You can use an observer to print it to the console, see my edit

Comment: Thanks. Let me check